# GAC (64bit system) comparison?

Tags: .net, powershell

How to compare the 64bit systems GAC using powershell?

Parameters:
Assembly name
full name
version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're after but if it is to compare 32-bit and 64-bit GAC'd assemblies try something like this:

```
PS> $gac64 = gci C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64 -r *.dll | 
    select @{n='AQN';e={"$($_), $((Split-Path $_.PSParentPath -leaf) -split '__' -join ', ')"}} | 
    Sort AQN
PS> $gac32 = gci C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32 -r *.dll | 
    select @{n='AQN';e={"$($_), $((Split-Path $_.PSParentPath -leaf) -split '__' -join ', ')"}} | 
    Sort AQN

PS> diff $gac32 $gac64 -Property AQN

AQN                                                         SideIndicator
---                                                         -------------
Mcx2Dvcs.dll, 6.1.0.0, 31bf3856ad364e35                     =>
Microsoft.MediaCenter.Interop.dll, 6.1.0.0, 31bf3856ad36... =>
Microsoft.MediaCenter.iTV.Media.dll, 6.1.0.0, 31bf3856ad... =>
Microsoft.MediaCenter.Mheg.dll, 6.1.0.0, 31bf3856ad364e35   =>
Microsoft.MediaCenter.Playback.dll, 6.1.0.0, 31bf3856ad3... =>
Microsoft.MediaCenter.TV.Tuners.Interop.dll, 6.1.0.0, 31... =>
Microsoft-Windows-HomeGroupDiagnostic.NetListMgr.Interop... =>
SoapSudsCode.dll, 2.0.0.0, b03f5f7f11d50a3a                 =>
Expression.DevHost.dll, 3.0.0.4000, 31bf3856ad364e35        <=
Expression.DevHost.resources.dll, 3.0.0.4000_en_31bf3856... <=
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2.dll, 3.0.0.0, 31bf3856... <=
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.dll, 3.0.0.0, 31bf3856ad364e35 <=
```

Note that the splitting isn't foolproof (pretty naive impl) but it should be sufficient to compare what's different between 32-bit and 64-bit GAC.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Can you please elaborate the command line?
$gac64 = gci C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64 -r *.dll |  
    select @{n='AQN';e={"$($_), $((Split-Path $_.PSParentPath -leaf) -split '__' -join ', ')"}} |  
    Sort AQN 

so that i can customize as per my requirement.

Comment: gci path -r *.dll gets all the dlls located at path recursively.  The select (select-object) cmdlet, can project the incoming object (a Syste.IO.FileInfo) to another object (PSCustomObject) by taking various properties from FileInfo, manipulating those properties in a single property called AQN.  Select-Object accepts a hashtable to define this project where the Name entry ('n' for short) defines the property name and the Expression entry ('e' for short) defines the value of the property.